# Accessing a range of elements from a vector

Tags: c++

There is a list of objects say for example:- Rectangle objects in a list,  like
std::list. I need to get a list of 50 objects(at a time) from the list and then grab individual elements from each Rectangle as length and breadth and form a string of sizes(length, breadth) of first 50, and then the next 50 and so forth until the end...

I am trying to figure out  a way to code this using boost functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give any details of how those strings should be formatted, but the general iteration could be of this form:

```
int j;
string work;
vector<string> strings;
for(list<Rectangle>::iterator i = l.begin(); i != l.end(); i++,j++)
{
    int len = i->length, br = i->breadth;
    work += something_based_on(len,br);
    if(j == 50)
    {
        strings.push_back(work);
        work.clear();
        j = 0;
    }
}
```

This doesn't use boost, though.